# Consume an "asp service" with Java (without WSDL)

Tags: java, asp.net, xml, web-services

I'm not sure about the exact denomination, but I have an "web asp service" (from a .NET application) who gives me a XML file. (There is no WSDL...)

For exemple, I can question the web service with an URL like that :

```
http://Connectiquetest:86/Vaudoise/srv_db/db2_personnes.asp?Nopers=529720&SearchMode=1&Name=Smith
```

Where Nopers=52920, SearchMode=1 and Name=Smith are used to return to me the response I want. (The URL is for an internal system, you cannot access to it without a VPN)

The content type return is : "text/xml" (it's a classic well-formed XML).

So, how can I use this informations to make a call from a Java application to receive the XML ? Anybody can tell me what is it exactly (maybe a specific implementation of SOAP ?)

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most simple (and yet most labor intensive) approach would be to open an [`HttpURLConnection`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html). You can do that by calling [`URL.openConnection()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URL.html#openConnection%28%29). The `URL` object would obviously be based on the URL you mentioned, optionally appending the parameters `Nopers`, `SearchMode` and `Name`. You could then call `getInputStream()` to access the response of the call. Next would be parsing the XML to interpret the result.

However, as said, this requires a lot of low-level code (especially when reading the input, parsing the XML, and so on). Consider using something like [Apache HttpComponents](http://hc.apache.org/) for HTTP-related work, combined with something like [JAXB](https://jaxb.java.net/) for easily converting the retrieved XML to plain old Java objects.

Using JAXB might require you to have an XML schema. In the ideal situation, it already exists (written by the people who wrote the ASP service). In the sub-ideal situation, you'll have to derive it yourself.

Comment: Thanks, That's something like I expected. I will try this soon. Currently I already have an exemple of the xml file returned, so I already make a parser with XStream to have an object representation.